# How do I add an appended object as part of a shapekey?

Tags: shape-keys

[image]

So the shield is part of a shapekey. It does not exist in the "basis" shapekey.

The skull I made in a separate blend file and appended it to this file. I now want to join the skull and shield together. So they are both part of the shield's shapekey. Is this possible? Or will I need to recreate the skull in edit mode whilst in the new shapekey?

Hope this is making sense :S

Answer (score 0):

Select the shield and afterwards the skull, and press ctrl + j. This joins the meshes together and creates a new object and should fix your issue, unless I understood it wrongly.

Comment: I have already tried that. It doesn't fix it. If I then reduce the value of the shapekey down to 0 only the shield dissapears and the skull remains. I need both the skull and shield to dissapear when the value is reduced to 0 and reappear when the shapekey value is increased to 1... Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For shapekeys all of the vertices have to be present on the basis shapekey. Any modification on the number of vertices between shapekeys will have unexpected results. If you modify the geometry, you should erase all shape keys and start over.